# foreach loops showing illegal string error

Tags: php, foreach

I'm new to php i'm working on foreach loop in my project. but i'm getting `Illegal string offset 'fname'`.

php code

```
    <?php

    $arr = array(
        'fname'=>'tom',
        'lname'=>'jerry'
    );
    
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arr);
    echo '</pre>';
    
    foreach($arr as $item){
        echo $item['fname'];
    }
?>
```

Here i need to display only `tom`. HOW CAN I DO IT.

### THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need foreach to print tom.
Simply do this:

```
 $arr = array(
        'fname'=>'tom',
        'lname'=>'jerry'
    );

echo $arr['fname'];
```

Output:

```
tom
```

I don't know why do you want to do it through forech.Any way try this:

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){

  $new[$key] = $value;  

}

 echo $new['fname'];
```

**OR**

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){

  if($key=='fname'){echo $value;} 

}
```

Comment: but how can we achieve this through `foreach` loop.

Comment: @TomJerry did it helped?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a foreach loop to access the elements in an associative array. Take a look at this example.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_array_assoc

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    'fname'=>'tom',
    'lname'=>'jerry'
);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';

echo $arr['fname'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two values in your array variable..
When you loop your array through `foreach` it will iterate n number of times. Where n is the number of indexes in your array.

Eg. If your array holds 2 values and when you pass it in foreach it will iterate 2 times.

First time you will get value as you expecting, second time it will printed value of index 1.

If you want to print the value of first index you don't need to loop your array just do this:

```
$arr = array(
    'fname'=>'tom',
    'lname'=>'jerry'
);

echo $arr['fname']; // Output => tom
```